# Use own modules in beeware

Tags: python, import, module, beeware

I have a beeware project and also want to use my own modules in it like Models and Controllers. Also, a module which creates some objects I can test with.

But when I want to import the module to create the test objects and use the method it just throws an error:

```
ImportError: attempted relative import beyond top-level package
```

After some research, I know that the path (directory) structures, where I put my modules in, and where the package is, are important. But where ever I put the modules it has the same (or kinda like this) errors. But I can import my Models to create objects of these classes. I also can't decide where the start point of the briefcase is.

Here my structure currently:

```
/Project_Dir (own created)
/briefcase_project (created from briefcase)
/src
  /Models (own created)
  /app_directory (created from briefcase)
      here is the __main__.py and the __init__.py (the start point I guess) and the app.py (where beeware code is, and also my module import from Test)
  /Test (own created, here is a file with a method I want to call)
```

Sadly there is not so much stuff to find about beeware so I could find a solution.

Please help. Thanks ^^

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I did the following to workaround the issue. The example using the  [Beeware Tutorial 2](https://docs.beeware.org/en/latest/tutorial/tutorial-2.html) source code is on [Github](https://github.com/zasoliton/beeware_custom_lib)

```
.
├── __init__.py
├── __main__.py
├── app.py
├── mylib               <--- # my lib.
│   ├── __init__.py
│   └── testlib.py
└── resources
    ├── __init__.py
    ├── beewarecustomlibexample.icns
    ├── beewarecustomlibexample.ico
    └── beewarecustomlibexample.png

2 directories, 9 files
```

The `mylib/testlib.py`

```
def test(text: str) -> str:
    return f"Hello: {text}"
```

In the `app.py`:

```
import toga
from toga.style import Pack
from toga.style.pack import COLUMN, ROW

from beewarecustomlibexample.mylib.testlib import test  # Import custom lib


class BeewareCustomLibExample(toga.App):
    def startup(self):

        ...

    def say_hello(self, widget):
        # Calling my test method
        result = test(self.name_input.value)
        self.main_window.info_dialog("Test Dialog", result)


def main():
    return BeewareCustomLibExample()
```

The above is how I got it working. I've built it on MacOS and works fine.

Answer (score 0):

Take your project folder name and then import from there, so if you're tinkering with the tutorial and you've set up a module folder called `myModule` in the same directory as your `app.py` and you have a file called `file.py` with a class called `myClass`, you might type:

```
from helloworld.myModule.file import myClass
```